# Find link of tag a href and replace with new link using jquery/wordpress code

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have 1 old link call "https://oldlink.com" in my frontend homepage. I want to use jquery to find old link and replace it with new link "https://newlink.com", or wordpress code (I like jquery more than wordpress code because I'm understand it but still like some answer about wp code)

Any idea for this? I know how to loop href and check it but the code is too long and effect my speed website, not good for speed.

Comment: maybe something like `$('a[href="https://oldlink.com"]').attr('href', 'https://newlink.com');`, and just add it in a document ready statement

Comment: Is there a reason you are not wanting to update the link URL in the HTML?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, Thank you, your answer is very simple and helpful.

Comment: @wouch, yes, it's some personal reason. With answer of Carsten, it's OK now